# Should we add OSS ads (targeted at users)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

There is this question "[Should we add the SE network OSS ads?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1005/should-we-add-the-se-network-oss-ads)" about whether to re-use the SE ads which aim at gathering new developers. One of the comments is that those ads aren't a good match for AU because we're not primarily developers but *users*. So:

**Should we host OSS ads on AU *that are targeted towards users*, in a similar fashion as those SE ads?**

Answer (score 4):

We have enabled the ability for the Ubuntu community to have control over ads placed on the homepage and question landing pages.  See:  [Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2011](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1089/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I don't think there's any point. Maybe that's just me though.

I think it will only publicise the already popular applications. People follow places like OMG Ubuntu to find out what the latest and greatest apps are.

And if programs are good, they will naturally be mentioned in answers to questions.

Comment: why?it will give many new floss software exposure.

Comment: @Alaukik I updated my answer to give more details

Comment: they can advertise lesser known floss software.