# Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2011

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2012](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2158/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool Ubuntu applications
- the site's Twitter account
- Ubuntu scripts or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (Imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

#### Display and Statistics

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click statistics [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/ads/display/1089).

Comment: i was seeing these ads yesterday but these are not shown today.

Comment: @Alaukik They are in rotation - there's a 50% chance they will be shown in rotation with other house ads.

Comment: +1 - I've been waiting for this!

Comment: Can we please have a stats page to see CTR (click-through-rate) and stuff like that?

Comment: I'm going to draw!!! =D Glad!

Answer (score 52):

[image: Everything Ubuntu. Daily.]

Comment: I have found out many interessing things about ubuntu with this website.

Answer (score 50):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Answer (score 43):

[image: Unity : Hackers wanted!]

Comment: Source files: [unity-3.8.10_ad.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3296856/unity-3.8.10_ad.zip) (0.5 MB)

Comment: This needs to be updated for new Unity look (dash icon)

Answer (score 41):

[image: Learn how to write great applications for Ubuntu -- Quickly]

Comment: Maybe this need to use Ubuntu Mono font as part of the background design?

Answer (score 41):

[image: The GNU Image Manipulation Program]

Answer (score 36):

[image: The lively podcast made by members of the Ubuntu UK LoCo includes debates, interesting points, news, competitions and much more]

Comment: Class +1 no need for all that in your face orange, don't want people thinking were a mobile company ;)

Answer (score 35):

[image: WebUpd8 - Ubuntu / Linux news and app reviews]

Comment: Good quality blog, plenty of Unicorns and not too many trolls

Comment: Very good site. The articles are clean and almost immaculate. The author also maintains more than a couple of PPAs and has recently introduced a 'mini-blog' to publish the changelogs for the packages in them. There's much more to it than what the banner is telling us.

Comment: This blog is very objective and impartial. What I really love is that it is not a tabloid blog. Nice, Andrew.

Answer (score 28):

[image: Lauchpad]

Comment: Our good pal!!!

Comment: very nice indeed!

Answer (score 26):

[image: StackApplet Screenshot]

Comment: I don't get it this application future, it just showing only reputation. it will be nice showing the new post questions :)

Comment: @Achu: What are you asking?

Comment: It isn't clear from either the screenshot or the linked page exactly what this will do, besides showing reputation.  Which sorts of "status" and information can it show?  Will it show when comments are replied to, or I'm mentioned in chat, or answers to my questions?  What about when interesting new questions on tags I care about come in?  **Update**:  Ahh - there is no "documentation" at the linked page, but there is a "home page" with more info.  Perhaps better to link to the home page?

Comment: @neal: Ya... you're right.

Answer (score 22):

[image: THE INDEPENDENT MAGAZINE FOR THE UBUNTU COMMUNITY]

Comment: I slightly sharpened the inner part of the red circle and have redone the lower part fonts.

Comment: do you like to read... do you like to have in your computer all this wonderful issues get this script .... [wget -c http://dl.fullcirclemagazine.org/issue{1..54}_en.pdf] happy reading...

Answer (score 21):

[image: Zeitgeist Project: our motivation is to bring the element of human context awareness to computer systems, paving the way for more user friendly and easier to use software.]

Comment: The writing on it is too cramped.

Comment: I've padded this image so it's not squished; for now. This is the [original](http://i.imgur.com/HHZ57.png).

Comment: Awesome to see such cool "advertisements" here

Comment: Normally I'd agree with Oxwivi, but I found the logo so compelling that it induced me to read more, and I'm already a zeitgeist fan. However, ALL CAPS ARE REALLY teh SUXXORS anywhere. :p

Comment: This seems adware.

Comment: @pedrorolo Do you mean [Zeitgeist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist_(framework))?

Answer (score 18):

[image: Devops Distilled]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Is it me or is the image slightly blurred?

Comment: @Yi, it's you. You possibly need glasses.

Comment: @Oxwivi Well yes, Alaukik came in 5 hours ago and replaced the old blurred one with a sharp version ;)

Comment: @Yi, my bad, I didn't notice the timing of the last edit and your comment.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Ubuntu Developer Week]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Ubuntu App Developer Week]

Answer (score 13):

[image: 2-4 March 2012]

Comment: Source [SVG file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/673326/global_jam.svg).

Answer (score 13):

[image: Ubuntu Open Week]

Answer (score 12):

[image: This year it's all about Ubuntu]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Yet another ubuntu blog]

Comment: I like it. unique and colorful, and clean...

Comment: The "yet..." text is really small, and the serifs+aliasing makes it difficult to read.

Comment: I see blurry text

Comment: @Greg: can you be a bit more descriptive/specific?

Answer (score 9):

[image: Come and follow our progress!]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Any help redoing this one would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

[image: SCALE 10x returns to the Hilton Los Angeles Airport Hotel!]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Ask Ubuntu on Google+]

Answer (score 7):

[image: This Week In Linux - Linux News, Reviews, and Tutorials]

Comment: I do not feel this is sufficiently ubuntu-specific to be included

Comment: The show does feature regular news and reviews of Ubuntu. Of course there's also news/reviews of other distros and related stuff, but it's something that I think would be of interest to many Ubuntu users.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with @JeffAtwood on this one.  This doesnt seem to be sufficiently ubuntu-specific to include.

Comment: According to the rules in the "question" at the top, sites don't have to be Ubuntu-specific, they have to be of interest to Ubuntu users...?

Answer (score 6):

[image: Discover what's new in ubuntu]

Comment: help us build our ubuntu community blog, you can also participate by sending your article or news here :)

Comment: I didn't know Ubuntu Buzz before, but it seems like a nice site with info about Ubuntu and applications that run on it.

Comment: Who are those people apart from generic-mixed-race-stock-photo-people?

Answer (score 6):

[image: Linux Outlaws - The hardest-hitting Linux podcast around.]

Comment: Maybe I need glasses, but I can't read that without squinting and getting really close to the monitor

Answer (score 6):

[image: Come and chat!]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]