# Request for Community Promotion Ads artwork.

Tags: discussion

There are some events in the Ubuntu Community that I'd love to run as [Community Promotion Ads](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1089/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011), but unfortunately I don't have the skill to make nice looking ads, so this is a place where people can request ads for that thread and people can make ads.

Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

After you make it just post it to the promotion thread and mark it off here as "done" or something.

Answer (score 7):

I would appreciate if someone who is GIMP-enabled would help us out by helping us promote these community events.

- An ad for [the Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/b/107921963368679288414/), similar to the twitter ad.

Answer (score 3):

Some one should do an ad for gimp (preferably made in gimp!).

Comment: did it my self http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1089/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011/1183#1183