# Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5504/community-promotion-ads-2013)

We... may have left 1H 2011 running a whole half-year long extra. Whoops. Well, now we begin-anew the next round of Community Promotion Ads!

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool Ubuntu applications
- the site's Twitter account
- Ubuntu scripts or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (Imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

#### Display and Statistics

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click statistics [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/ads/display/2158).

Comment: [See last years ads](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1089/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011)

Comment: OK here's the thing, by voting on what ads should be shown, you will ensure that already popular things get advertised and by definition these will be the things which need adverts the least.

Comment: @GraceNote Time for the second half ads?

Answer (score 34):

[image: Lauchpad]

Comment: Join what team?

Comment: The team of LaunchPad. We register ourselves into LaunchPad to report bugs, request features, submit fixes, translate software ... to make Ubuntu and its software better.

All of us, users LauchPad, we form a team that works for the construction and evolution of the open-source software.

Answer (score 33):

[image: Everything Ubuntu. Daily.]

Answer (score 31):

[image: Ask Ubuntu on Google+]

Answer (score 30):

[image: Find new apps]

Answer (score 29):

[image: Learn how to write great applications for Ubuntu -- Quickly]

Comment: This one should be updated with the Ubuntu Mono font!

Answer (score 28):

[image: Unity : Hackers wanted!]

Answer (score 23):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Answer (score 22):

[image: WebUpd8 - Ubuntu / Linux news and app reviews]

Answer (score 20):

[image: Juju, Isn't it Charming.]

Comment: I never really liked how the `isn't it` and `ing` on *Charming* appear aliased.

Comment: can anyone please please give me a simple example of the benefits of JuJu and keep in mind that the person who is reading your example is a noob one. :-)

Answer (score 18):

[image: Getting Started with Ubuntu can be a little dangerous - this book aims to make it easy and enjoyable.]

Answer (score 17):

[image: The Ubuntu Subreddit: Ubuntu news. All of it.]

Comment: [The XCF source layers are available here](http://www.mediafire.com/?w8gyw43ppx3qass). Improvements from the stylistically adept welcome!

Answer (score 16):

[image: The lively podcast made by members of the Ubuntu UK LoCo includes debates, interesting points, news, competitions and much more]

Answer (score 15):

[image: Devops Distilled]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Come and follow our progress!]

Answer (score 12):

[image: How to Ubuntu!]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Create desktop apps from webapps]

Comment: Description from the link: `Fogger acts as a bridge between web applications and the linux desktop. It exposes an easy to use JS API to webapps which can be used to interact with the host desktop environment. It can also be used to write basic desktop apps for linux in pure web style.`

Comment: If it's going to appear in an ad section, you might want some kind of descriptive text to inspire a clickthrough

Comment: [Juju](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2172/22949) doesn't have any descriptive text...

Comment: @EliahKagan - fair point, but at the time of the comment it had a word i could google.  this did not

Comment: Fogger doesn't seem to be around anymore.

Comment: @iSeth It's there for 12.04. 12.10 + 13.04 version will come out soon.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Ubuntu news for human beings]

Comment: This website needs an "about" page. I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @flimm its a ubuntu blog. I will file  that in our bugtracker.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Show your interest in cloud computing!]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Latest Ubuntu/Linux Apps and Games Reviews]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Visit the website today!]

Comment: IMHO, looks too much like a regular ad.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Gmail notifier for Ubuntu]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: It's not obvious to me what this is advertising. An RSS feed that displays my [email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbox)? The ability to view RSS feeds in my email client? The only identifying content is tiny, low-contrast, aliased, and blurred.

Comment: It's an RSS feed containing the contents of your Stack Exchange inbox. So that would contain, for example, notifications of new answers, comments, etc.

Comment: Thanks. With effort I did figure it out, but an effective ad should make it *obvious*.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 6):

[image: netsniff-ng - the packet sniffing beast]

Answer (score 6):

[image: We need you!]

Comment: According to the question, "...you might promote the following things: ...anything else your community would genuinely be interested in." Because a number of Ask Ubuntu community members own e-book readers, I figured this would be an appropriate ad to display in the usual rotation.

Answer (score 5):

[image: community-ads]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Download ShowMyFaves, a bookmarks manager, which can do more than manage your bookmarks...]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Parcel Tracker]

Answer (score 3):

[image: My name is Srinivas Gowda, and this is my personal blog. All of the silly things that I rant about here are my own experience, so you can blame me.]

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I made a add using material on your site. that will fit the parameters of the add, and better reflect your site.

Comment: Looks awesome, thanks again bro ;).