# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool Ubuntu applications
- the site's Twitter account
- Ubuntu scripts or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/ads/display/5504).

Comment: The awesome part about the Meta section is that you don't feel like a jerk for downvoting stuff. :) This makes it perfect for getting honest opinions about the submissions.

Answer (score 48):

[image: Develop your apps for Ubuntu phone!]

Answer (score 43):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: Original design by @GraceNote: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/77fWg.png)

Comment: nice! awesome job on the update @efthialex

Comment: This violates the [Twitter Trademark and Content Display Policy](https://twitter.com/logo), which explicitly prohibits using speech bubbles around the bird, rotating the bird, and changing the color of the bird.

Comment: @efthialex I updated to reflect Twitter Trademark policy.

Comment: or, using Ubuntu's "tweet pictogram"  http://i.stack.imgur.com/vLh2v.png

Answer (score 41):

[image: Launchpad]

Comment: Amith KK, you had posted many entries in CPA 2013. I really see in your act a wish to prevent entries of previous years to be missed. I myself don´t care about your attitude as I already was to post again my entry, but I think that if I wanted to change something, I would feel kind of disrespected as I, as creator of the image, wanted to update it and someone without asking nothing just repost it as if I couldn´t change the image.

Comment: It is not my case, but I think that this is a valid opinion and I think you shouldn´t repost, so the creator won´t be missed, in my opinion you should have waited a period to just repost the missed entries. And just for you to know I am not just seeing the CPA 2013 now, I saw it only a few days after it was opened although you had already posted my entry, I though to share my opinion that time, but I forgot to do so and now I am just posting it with some lag, sorry ^^

Comment: @RodrigoMartins Sorry :) . Well.. that was the only sane way to get all the ads in rotation asap

Comment: No need to sorry, I think that anybody was "hurt" with your act, if I were you I just had waited a bit to see if the creators were reposting their entries or making new ones, and then if I see that some was missed I would repost. I am saying it constructively ;)

Answer (score 41):

[image: Vim the editor]

Comment: Ah yes, the one true editor.

Comment: @jrg Sorry. Emacs is the one true editor/OS/IDE/mail reader/organizer/psychiatrist....

Comment: can't do calculus in vim, emacs has my vote!

Comment: Vim holds a special place in my heart but I just don't feel comfortable recommending it to most of the people I refer to this site.

Comment: vim is so so cool! everyone should learn to use it - once you do it , you won't use anything else.

Answer (score 36):

[image: Everything Ubuntu. Daily.]

Answer (score 34):

[image: Ubuntu Touch]

Comment: Is it just me or are the icons to the left and on the phone a bit blurry?

Comment: @minerz029 Now that you mention it, they are a little blurry. That could just be the size though.

Answer (score 33):

[image: WebUpd8 - Ubuntu / Linux news and app reviews]

Answer (score 31):

[image: Getting Started with Ubuntu can be a little dangerous - this book aims to make it easy and enjoyable.]

Answer (score 31):

[image: Ubuntu One is your personal cloud!]

Comment: Original design by @green7: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MQWZp.png)

Comment: @efthialex amazing work! Great! :)

Comment: Nice work, this one looks great!

Answer (score 23):

[image: Find new apps]

Comment: Not sure "apps" is really the best word. Software might be a better option.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, USC official name is Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 22):

[image: Unity : Join the revolution.]

Answer (score 21):

[image: Ask Ubuntu on Google+]

Answer (score 20):

[image: The Ubuntu Subreddit: Ubuntu news. All of it.]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Juju, Isn't it Charming.]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Find your Local Community.]

Answer (score 17):

[image: darktable | the photo workflow software]

Answer (score 15):

[image: A network file-sharing application that makes sending a file to another machine on the local network as easy as dragging-and-dropping.]

Answer (score 14):

[image: How to Ubuntu!]

Comment: This link is broken. I'm just getting a "Sorry, we can't find that post" page.

Comment: Thanks @ændrük I had no idea query strings broke my URLs.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Planet Ubuntu is a window into the world, work and lives of Ubuntu developers and contributors.]

Comment: Don't think this will work, needs to be 220x250 pixels.

Comment: @JorgeCastro I just modified it, now it's 220x250 as you said.

Comment: Awesome, looks great!

Answer (score 12):

[image: GNU Emacs!]

Comment: @mateo_salta Done. It is now 220x250 pixels.

Comment: I don't use Emacs, but I find this hard to read.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm it's the official logo for emacs afaik

Comment: I resized the logo to restore the original proportions inside the 220x250 canvas. Hope no one minds.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Create your own QR codes in Ubuntu!]

Comment: There is a new set of ad's out, Just to let you know. I Like the program and would like to see it on the new set of ad's :)

Answer (score 12):

[image: A free, open-source game of ancient warfare]

Answer (score 11):

[image: GNU nano the Text Editor]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Click to install FreeCiv]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Ubuntu for End Users]

Comment: It will soon have a Spanish version and an updated 13.10/14.04 version. More "user friendlish"

Answer (score 7):

[image: Ubuntu news for human beings]