# Ubuntu Edge Crowd Funding Ad

Tags: discussion, feature-request

How can we add an Ad about the Ubuntu Edge Crowd Funding to Askubuntu. It can help the cause in raising the said amount.

Link: http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge

Something like this (BTW I suck add image editing)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a starter:

http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7048/44179

Unfortunately the image is a little skewed.. but it works until someone else comes up with something better ;)

Answer (score 15):

I think it'd be better to put the badge up there

[image: http://www.indiegogo.com/project/badge/461046]

Not sure how to get that up there with in the right size of the advert though.

[image]

I made this with a little php magic

Comment: I made [this](http://2buntu.com/1373/ubuntu-edge-crowdfunding-widget/) with Python. Any way that would help? The big problem here is that ads need to be hosted on `imgur.com` which is a problem for something that needs to dynamically update.

Comment: Maybe we could convince someone at SE to stick the image on the sidebar or something. One minor suggestion - the progress bar is not anti-aliased and looks blocky.