# Anyone interested in a regularly scheduled, multiplayer game of 0 A.D.?

Tags: discussion, fun, community-event

> **Note:** check out [this post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14905/community-event-multi-player-0-a-d-game-2016-01-17) for details of an upcoming event.

I am interested in setting up a regularly scheduled game of [0 A.D.](http://play0ad.com/) that would be open to all Ask Ubuntu users. Since 0 A.D. is a free and open-source game that [can easily be installed in Ubuntu](http://trac.wildfiregames.com/wiki/LatestReleaseLinux#Ubuntu), I thought it might be a nice way to bring the community together while still having a great time.

Here's what we'll be doing:

[image]

If someone with a reliable Internet connection would be willing to host the game, that would be great. I am willing to host the game between 5pm EST and 8pm EST on Sundays, but if someone else is available at other times, then that's cool too.

What does everyone think of this?

> ### First Game Scheduled for Oct. 13, 2013 at 5PM EDT
>
> <sub>[[click to view in other timezones]](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=Stack+Exchange+0+A.D.+Game&iso=20131013T14&p1=1085&ah=7)</sub>
>
> I am pleased to announce that we will be having our first game this weekend. The game will start at the time scheduled above, so be sure to show up early to make sure you get to play.
>
> We will be using the map "Azure Coast 1," which allows for up to **eight** players. Players will be allowed into the game on a first-come-first-served basis - so don't just show up at the last minute! I'll try to get the server started fifteen minutes in advance.
>
> #### Connection Details:
>
> I will be hosting the game, so you will need to use the following hostname when joining:
>
> ```
> home.quickmediasolutions.com
> ```
>
> Also be sure you are running the latest version of 0 A.D.

Comment: Would it be possible to host it on a server?

Comment: @jrg: Probably not since currently the only way to do so involves the server acting as a client. (As far as I know.)

Comment: @jrg if this was like FreeCiv, we would be sure that it is possible... sadly with 0AD is not http://www.wildfiregames.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=14270

Comment: 0 AD will get a dedicated server eventually but it's still pretty fresh.

Comment: You might want ask over at http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com too :)

Comment: If you want a more stable 0 A.D. experience, please contribute to the 0 A.D. indiegogo page -> http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/support-0-a-d-an-open-source-strategy-game

Comment: I can host it on my laptop all the time it is on (assuming 0 A.D. doesn't consume too much resources). My laptop is typically on from 8 A.M. to 8 P.M. IST all days of the week.

Answer (score 8):

### Summary of Oct. 13, 2013 Game

I thought I ought to write a brief summary of what happened with our scheduled game. Five users (including myself) showed up:

- [Me](https://askubuntu.com/users/5/nathan-osman) and my brother
- [Mateo](https://askubuntu.com/users/47291/mateo)
- [user320](https://askubuntu.com/users/194862/user320)
- [John](https://askubuntu.com/users/5179/john)

One team consisted of two players and two AI bots and the other team consisted of three players and one AI bot.

Unfortunately, there were a few issues:

- Some error messages were displayed now and then, which we ignored.
- Sometimes players were unable to see their allies.
- user320 lost his connection about forty minutes in and was unable to reconnect.
- At that same point, the game started briefly freezing every so often, which was annoying.

Then after about an hour of gameplay, the game stopped working for me (announcing that the connection to the server had been lost) and everyone was disconnected. Since I was the host, this also meant the game had come to a premature end.

This was a rather disappointing finish, but we enjoyed the time that we *did* have playing the game. There are no plans to try this again until we sort a few of the issues out.

We do have one screenshot taken by John:

[image: 0 A.D.]

Thanks again to all participants!

Comment: Remember to report the issues since the game is still *green* and need fixes. BTW, UI's aren't capable to use boats (or any navigation for what matters) hence in a highly watery map AI are in disadvantage.

Comment: Alpha 15 is due in November-ish... around that time then?

Comment: I really recommend using a map with less water. I know water is fun, but it would make the game so much smoother and would probably prevent some of the connection issues and freezes you had. At least, that's my experience.

Comment: I think the problem with the crash at the ned is that a. the game is single threaded, which mean that a lot of computing power is going to waste. Also Once there are a lot of characters in a map fighting the computer has trouble with the little power it gets form the one cpu.

Comment: 0 A.D. is now also in the askubuntu community ads: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5504/community-promotion-ads-2013/7569#7569

Answer (score 0):

I would win every time, so there is no point in playing against me.

LOL just kidding :D
I'm interested! My only (current) limitation is my hardware, due to the graphics card more so than anything else I think.