# Community Event - multi-player 0 A.D. game [2016-01-17]

Tags: discussion, community-event

A couple years ago, some of the community members here on Ask Ubuntu [scheduled and organized a game of 0 A.D.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7418/anyone-interested-in-a-regularly-scheduled-multiplayer-game-of-0-a-d) Since that time, the game has improved considerably and we are thinking of trying another game.

### The Game

*"So what exactly is this game?"*

0 A.D. is a multi-player strategy game in active development that allows each player to assume control of a civilization that battles for world domination. Each civilization is modelled to reflect the strengths and weaknesses of a group of people from the hypothetical year "0 A.D."

The game permits each player to control one of the civilizations. They become responsible for giving orders to units - gathering resources, building civil structures, and engaging in combat.

[Here's a link to the installation instructions...](https://askubuntu.com/q/355273/36315)

### The Event

*"Sounds cool - I'm in. Now what?"*

I am scheduling the game for **2 P.M. PST on January 17, 2016 ([click here to view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=0+A.D.+Game&iso=20160117T22&p1=%3A))**. This means you should show up in the [Ask Ubuntu General Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) roughly *10 minutes prior to the game*. I'll be going over the details of the game at that time.

I'll be hosting the game on my desktop. I looked into hosting the game on a dedicated server, but this was ruled out due to reliability issues running the game on a virtual X server.

The connection details will be as follows:

**Hostname:** `home.quickmediasolutions.com`
**Port:** `20595` (make sure you can make outbound connections from this port)

### Practice

*"I've never played this game before. How does it work?"*

If you want to get some practice in or you want to learn how the game works, run these commands to install it on your computer:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:wfg/0ad
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install 0ad
```

**Note:** the version of this package in the archives is *not up-to-date* (unless you are running Xenial) so you *must* install the game from the PPA. Only players running **Alpha 19** will be able to participate.

**Make sure you download the game beforehand! It's quite large and takes ~40 minutes over a 20Mbps connection.**

Feel free to ask any questions regarding this event below.

Comment: From when on will we be able to test connections to home.quickmediasolutions.com 20595???  (seems to be closed right now; tested from both public server and my current home network)

Comment: @Fabby it will only be accessible when the game is being played :P

Comment: Awh, yeah peeeps!

Comment: In Amsterdam, that's  Sunday, 23:00. I have to work the next day. Any chance we can make it 20:00?

Comment: @blade19899 unfortunately, that's the earliest time I'm available. Maybe next time we'll do it Saturday night in my timezone.

Comment: For the people that want and in depth answer on what 0 A.D. actually is: [How do I Install 0 A.D.?](http://askubuntu.com/q/355273/36315)

Comment: Ah. no problem. Try to see If I can still play for like a half hour!

Comment: Well, dunno if I'll be able to stay for long, but maybe I can make it?

Comment: We already playing?

Comment: Why don't you provide a screenshot or two of the game? :)

Comment: I'll post screenshots when the game is done.

Answer (score 2):

### Game Summary

The game began at approximately 2:40pm and was soon restarted to select a different map. After resolving some connection problems, the game began. There was a lot of lag that really slowed down the game, but nobody was able to find the cause (I was able to rule out upstream bandwidth on my end).

The players included [myself](https://askubuntu.com/users/5/nathan-osman), my brother, [Mateo](https://askubuntu.com/users/47291/mateo), [Zacharee1](https://askubuntu.com/users/274320/zacharee1), and [Paranoid Panda](https://askubuntu.com/users/364819/paranoid-panda) split into two teams with three AI opponents (for a total of eight players).

The game went on for roughly an hour and a half before everyone either had to leave or was defeated.

#### Screenshots

<sub>Click the images for  larger version.</sub>

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think we know who was causing the lag... (Pasta ಠ_ಠ)

Comment: Well, I know for sure that my CPU was causing me a lot of lag until I shut down most of my applications except for `0ad`, however I don't see how that could have caused it for all of you...

Comment: But we should definitely do this again some time! :)

Comment: I'm thinking of doing this again but with some of the other free games that are available. I'll post something later with an update.