# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's the time of the year again, namely it is December 2013, and so we shall now refresh our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool Ubuntu applications
- the site's Twitter account
- Ubuntu scripts or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/ads/display/7773).

Comment: Where you have `Tagline to show on mouseover`, that is actually the Alt text. You need to place the mouseover text next to the link like `[2]: http://clickthrough-url "tagline text"`.

Comment: Ooooh... Where can you get Ubuntu Power Tools? Didn't know that about the rollover text.

Comment: @wilf I'm not sure you can just edit the question post, it's pretty magical (look down into the answer section).

Comment: Sorry, but I think my previous comment was wrong. Whilst in markdown, that is the alt text, in the actual ads, the alt text seems to be used for the rollover as well. Check it at http://meta.askubuntu.com/ads/display/7773. I was confused because the rollover didn't appear on this question ( @wilf )

Comment: Is there any time limit as to when(and until when) images can be posted?

Comment: @Aditya You can post these up until December, and they will stick around up until then.

Answer (score 41):

[image: Ubuntu Touch]

Comment: The icons on the left are a bit blurry. Is there any chance that can be fixed?

Comment: @NathanOsman You're not the first to notice that.. I think mateo was the one that came up with the graphic..

Comment: That should be better ;)

Comment: Thank you @NathanOsman for the new screens :)

Comment: Thanks for including the 2buntu app icon in the launcher :)

Comment: The new phone image was generated with **Device Art Generator** a tool from @NathanOsman : http://2buntu.com/touch/device-art-generator/

Answer (score 36):

[image: LibreOffice: The Document Foundation!]

Answer (score 31):

[image: Everything Ubuntu. Daily.]

Comment: Is it just me or does this 'Daily' in the OMG Ubuntu slogan remind you of the 'Daily' from the movie 300? `Fresh oracle will be delivered to you **Daily**. From all corners of the empire.`

Answer (score 27):

[image: GNU nano the Text Editor]

Comment: Is the ASCII art *supposed* to look like an eta (η) rather than a lower-case "n", the SI prefix for nano?

Comment: @NickT ask the nano people, this is their logo

Answer (score 27):

[image: Mozilla Firefox — Free Web Browser]

Comment: @minerz029 I edited it

Comment: @minerz029 And I accidentally made an [improved version: `http://i.stack.imgur.com/v11B8.jpg`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v11B8.jpg) - just copy the text, and replace  [`http://i.stack.imgur.com/PYZwp.png`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PYZwp.png) with [`http://i.stack.imgur.com/v11B8.jpg`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v11B8.jpg) :)

Comment: @wilf done, you're version is so much better :)

Comment: I think that whilst this image may be a good wallpaper, it isn't truly representative of 'Firefox' per se. An image using the original logo may be better. Here's a proof of concept I just made:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/JX6jk.png

Comment: @minerz029 I added it, clean, good looking, let the community decide which one to pick

Comment: @minerz029 fine, I removed the original

Comment: @minerz029 I know, it just seemed cleaner, besides anyone reading this post can still see the other version in the comments, so if firefox gets picked, they get to choose whatever they like

Comment: @minerz029 btw can i add more ads? i'd like to create ads for linux foundation, maintainer of the kernel kernel.org and linux.com, they are doing a wonderful job

Comment: @Fischer: You can go ahead and try, but be aware that these ads are for: "cool Ubuntu applications, 
the site's Twitter account, 
Ubuntu scripts or power tools, 
cool events or conferences, 
anything else your community would genuinely be interested in"

Comment: @minerz029 I see your point

Comment: @minerz029 good point, I edited the post

Comment: I want to redesign this so it looks like an icon from the Unity launcher, with appropriate colours and border. Maybe later tomorrow.

Comment: @minerz029 ok why not, I suck at designing stuff :) so if you design it, I'll update the post :)

Comment: @Fischer those would be awesome, those would probably fit in things "community would genuinely be interested in".

Comment: Note with any redesigns, you may want ro read- this](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/styleguide/identity/firefox/branding/) first - shouldn't be a issue with the current design, as it is basically one of those with a blue background and some text. All the design copyright stuff made Debian do their own version of Firefox called Iceweasel... though there are various nice spin-offs - e.g. http://i.imgur.com/CVGasrC.png

Comment: @Wilf brilliant spin-off wished i used that one

Answer (score 23):

[image: GNU Image Manipulation Program]

Comment: Shouldn't the link for this ad point to http://www.gimp.org instead of  the [link to download gimp for saucy](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gimp/)?

Answer (score 22):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. The image is courtesy [efthialex](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/121355/efthialex), who provided this during our previous cycle.

Answer (score 22):

[image]

Comment: This isn't 220x250 in size is it...

Comment: The image is now of the correct size and file format, I believe.

Comment: There was a cleaner (IMO, better) version posted last year. You may want to re-post (with attribution) or adapt the image [found here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6057/176889).

Comment: Its the same thing... thanks :)

Answer (score 21):

[image: A free, open-source game of ancient warfare]

Comment: what is the purpose of this?

Comment: @MinaMichael, this is a free and open-source software, and whe have on AU organized, some 0.A.D. gaming events.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Unity: Join the revolution.]

Comment: The icons on the left are a bit less than square (slightly squashed). I'll probably try to fix it if I have the time.

Comment: Thank you  ⁣ ⁣ ⁣

Answer (score 16):

[Tagline to show on mouseover http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/askubuntu.com/bounty.png](https://askubuntu.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: and Yes this will work - Ask Different has been using the same for ages see - http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1882/community-promotion-ads-2014/1884#comment3648_1884

Comment: Weird, I haven't seen it...

Comment: @Braiam on ask diffrent http://i.stack.imgur.com/dKAN0.png ? or here, (it isn't at 6 votes yet)

Comment: There are currently 18 bounties, and I just noticed it saying there are 17... oh well

Comment: @Wilf strange, I bet it counts only the active ones on the page, as you need to click "see all" to get the last one...

Comment: or they just haven't had that many bounties on Ask Different and is a bug..

Comment: @Mateo - I thought of whether it was checking the ones on AskDifferent, but [there's shows 5](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884), which is [right for their site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: @Mateo It's probably just a caching issue

Answer (score 15):

[image: A network file-sharing application that makes sending a file to another machine on the local network as easy as dragging-and-dropping.]

Answer (score 14):

[image: darktable | the photo workflow software]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Find your Local Community.]

Comment: I will ask if this could be modified to use some of the LoCo Council's artwork perhaps that was recently adopted?  There are [SVG pieces](http://lococouncil.ubuntu.com/2014/01/11/new-logos-announced/) that can be incorporated and the licensing means that my fellow councilors and I do not need to take further action to approve usage.

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat http://i.stack.imgur.com/AlhE3.png put together from your sources

Comment: I'm fine with replacing this. Is that the right thing to do with regard to peoples' votes? Or should the new image be its own submission so it has its own voting history?

Comment: cool, added http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/9086/47291 but pointed it to the LoCo Council page

Comment: Can we rotate the something so we can see the logo in the coffee a bit more?

Answer (score 12):

[image: We're looking for new writers too!]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Please help this site by reviewing!]

Comment: That's a.. odd photo. I personally think sabdfl has nothing to do with review.

Answer (score 11):

[image: GNU Emacs - The One True Editor]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Ubuntu For End Users]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Ask Ubuntu Meta - Customize Ask Ubuntu]

Comment: Linked to http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8422/how-do-we-get-more-ask-ubuntu-users-to-use-meta

Comment: why not gray???

Comment: @Braiam I will do a gray version tomorrow and provide the link.

Comment: @Braiam Changed the image to grayscale. The color image can be found at http://i.stack.imgur.com/AqG7F.png

Comment: Juts wondering, should the link for this ad point to http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-meta or http://meta.askubuntu.com?

Answer (score 10):

[image: Pipelight allows you to use Windows only plugins in Linux browsers. It supports Silverlight, Unity Webplayer, Shockwave, Flash and more.]

Comment: Please tell me if you think this ad could be improved, or download the source file: http://www.pwnicorn.tk/public/AU-Pipelight_xcf

Answer (score 9):

[image: The independent magazine for the Ubuntu Linux community]

Comment: why down voting? lets help this magazine (though i have never really read it) just saw it today and I thought, well they are doing what they're doing for ubuntu, and it seems free, good cause

Answer (score 8):

[image: Teckids e.V. – Erkunden, Entdecken, Erfinden – Discover, Explore, Forge]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Inksacpe - Draw Freely]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Lauchpad]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Pidgin, opensource chat client]

Comment: For an ad, you might want [`http://pidgin.im/about/`](http://pidgin.im/about/) as a link, as it has an explanation of what it is.

Comment: Theres a good short description on the main page, I think that's enough. It also features a nice list of supported protocols and a prominent download button.

And it's to consider that the home page is the intended landing page, it *is* what new users are supposed to see on their first visit, as decided by the owner of the page.

Answer (score 4):

[image: An open-source editor for experienced web designers and programmers, supporting many programming and markup languages, but focusing on creating dynamic and interactive websites.]

Comment: Why the downvote? The GIMP one was mostly copied, but I had to redesign this....

Answer (score 4):

[image: friendly interactive shell]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Local Communities ROCK!]

Comment: Logos from: http://lococouncil.ubuntu.com/2014/01/11/new-logos-announced/ CC-BY-SA by Sam Hewitt, if you see this - awesome job, and hope you like the implementation for this ad.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Chromium is an open-source browser project that aims to build a safer, faster, and more stable way for all Internet users to experience the web.]

Comment: Vote as you like - I thought I would see what the opinion on this would be.

Answer (score 3):

[image: WebUpd8 is an Ubuntu / Linux blog which delivers daily news, tips and application reviews.]

Comment: After having found *another* great article from this site, I thought it would be time to make an community ad for it

Answer (score -2):

[image: Dennis M. Ritchie - Father of the C Programming Language]

Comment: Shamelessly copied from unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I find it ironic that the "ad" for Dennis Ritchie is by far the most popular "ad" on Unix&Linux meta, but earns a negative vote here! The difference in outlook between the two communities, which I still valiantly think of as related if not mirror images, astounds me!

Comment: Well, just a face isn't exactly going to cut it IMO (to clarify, I didn't downvote here, but I'd not upvote it on U&L either). See the Ken discussion for more.

Comment: @mirabilos As you probably have noticed, it is also "just a face" on Unix&Linux meta, but there it is the most upvoted "ad" there. Why is there such a huge divide between the two communities?

Answer (score -2):

[image: Mark Shuttleworth, Founder of Ubuntu. Self Appointed Benevolent Dictator For Life.]

Comment: Odd this had so many down votes... You could put in the top bit means "Self-Appointed Benevolent Dictator for Life", though that might not make it any more popular... Also that fact that he only invested **$10 Million** in Ubuntu...

Comment: It is in the rollover, and is also his twitter handle

Answer (score -4):

[image: Ken Thompson - Father of Unix]

Comment: @Mateo Image size fixed. I am surprised that the father of all Unix systems, including indirectly Linux, is not more popular here.

Comment: It is just a picture... and the rollover only has a non capitalized "ken" so... I recognize the other, but maybe a baseball card treatment would work better - with name and short what they are famous for.

Comment: @Mateo Ken Thompson, the father of Unix. We would not be using Ubuntu if he had not written AT&T Unix in 1970!

Comment: Right, that is what you need to convey in this add... Right now it is just a face.

Comment: Also... something like [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Thompson) could be more descriptive.

Comment: @Wilf Point taken. I also was somewhat dissapointed about his Bell Labs webpage ( unlike that for dmr ). It did seem more traditional though and probably done by him or on his behalf with his blessing. I did change the link to his Wikipedia page/biography. I am still very surprised by the negative votes on Ask Ubuntu. On unix.stackexchange.com dmr is the most popular community "ad" and Ken Thompson is not too far behind. I suspect people are expressing their gratitude to dmr for C and everything else he did, particularly after his passing.

Answer (score -10):

[image: Look on our treasures for make benefit.]

Comment: I ... don't know what to say.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat On Sale now! Much Excite!! High Five!?