# Can we have a 'current bounties' ad on AU?

Tags: feature-request

Can whe have something like this on the community ads. Currently it gets rejected as to big. from here: [Community Promotion Ads - 2014 - Ask Different Meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1884/23664)

[Current Ask Ubuntu bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/bounty.png](https://askubuntu.com/?tab=featured)

When i try to download the image to rezise it, i get the following error:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be cool, I remember a while back we wanted to do this - and remember the guy who programed it made it so It could work on any of the stack exchange sites.

So here it is: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8593/47291

Also don't worry about the size or hosting.

1. The size is exact for "Retina" or High definition screens.
2. It is hosted at a place that is not going anywhere soon, and will still be shown. Ask Different has shown this to be possible and have been doing this for a long while, Also we hosted a dynamic image for "Ubuntu Edge" in the past that was not on immager.