# Do we need a event to clear out the Close Queue?

Tags: discussion, review

If you follow SO/MSO you will notice an event in the [Community Bulletin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223497/213575):

[image]

If you read up, SE has made some changes to the close queue in hopes to motivate close voters to... review. In the efforts they have [fuzzied the numbers of items in the queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199879/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut?lq=1), [made advertisements for rather obscure tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209779/stack-overflow-needz-moar-ads), [removing in batchs items with no/less reviews from the queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223349/213575), plus some other improvements, to get people reviewing. Now, we have +200 users with +3K reputation, ergo access to the close votes review queues, but even so questions sits there for a good while. What you think it can be done to get users review tasks in the review queue?

BTW, the current performance of SO is awesome, they triplicated the amount of reviewers, review tasks and completed reviews:

> Since I posted this challenge, **15,137 reviews have been done** in the close review queue, and a total of **6,829 review tasks have been completed.**

Comment: Personally I think it's quite boring to handle the close vote queue, beacuse most questions should be closed. But the other queues are interesting and constructive beacuse you can improve them and make them better in more ways. That's why I'm not doing so much in the close vote queue right now...

Comment: @Alvar you can select things that you don't find boring, like per tags questions or per close reason, like "opinion based". Just doing 1 a day is good ;)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Comment: Hmmmm... just the right size for [a Community Ad](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7773/community-promotion-ads-2014).... can I add it?

Comment: Sure, do we want it linked to just the review or the close queue?

Comment: just did [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8606/178596) with a bad rollover of `Please help this site by reviewing!`, and links through [to the review queue](http://askubuntu.com/review).

Comment: Ahh found where I got this.... do you have any files to make a high res new version plz?

Comment: I'll take a look, otherwise I can remake it ;)

Comment: ok here we go: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14925/community-promotion-ads-2016/15171#15171