# 1K close votes!!! Any celebrations?

Tags: discussion, review

Yes!! Finally we have reached the 1k close votes milestone!!
I Heartily congratulate all 3k rep users(except the [stewards](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/126/steward) and [others who try to shorten the list](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/stats)) for letting the queue to grow up to this Mark.

So have you planned any celebrations? If not I have some ideas, like

- Decrease close votes required from 5 to 3 or even 2.
- If 10k user votes to close, the post should be closed immediately.
- Allow 2k users to vote on close votes queue(If required, make there votes less valuable than 3k users)
- Allow tag gold badge earned users to close any type of question in the respective tag, not just duplicates(as it is currently)
- Plan some post-closing ceremonies.
- Notify 3k users from time to time that they can(and should) review close-votes queues

What are your ideas?

Comment: i think your question should be downvoted. We need to decrease the close vote review queue.

Comment: if it "If 10k user votes to close, the post should be closed immediately." would be implemented, 10kers should play with opening and closing.

Comment: @AvinashRaj blindly closing or leaving open a question is worse than that.

Comment: @AvinashRaj So you think you would play with opening and closing? :P

Comment: one would think some question should be closed and another would think that the same question should be opened. What's your solution for that type of situations?

Comment: @AvinashRaj AFAIK a user is allowed to vote only once in one direction on one post. So this should not be a problem.

Comment: Welcome to the price of success! Keep on voting/closing/rocking!

Comment: Commiserations on the conglomeration! But seriously, perhaps you should reach 3k first before judging.

Comment: @Mateo Made a little edit. I think it's better now.This problem was taken up by some one or other(including me) many times when it reached 400, 500, 800 etc and now 1k. But every time, we get the same message(directly or indirectly, to be understood), " [the queue grows because people don't review](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8604/184942) ".Also I'm not judging anything/anyone, there are only two possible reasons why the queue grew so large **1. people don't review 2.There are not enough people to review.** In both cases, some of my suggestions should help.Otherwise you may come up with yours.

Comment: I've read this post 3 times today and just didn't make sense to me. I couldn't figure out what you meant, or why you seemed so excited about it. However a celebration sounded like fun. I've just realized you were being sarcastic, and now the post makes sense.

Comment: Lovely sarcasm! One of the rare cases that sarcasm actually makes a point! +1 (though I agree with Jorge that this is also partially the price for success).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think growing number of reviews is a problem as such (at lease we are no where close to where Stack Overflow stands with about 100k items in queue) and we shouldn't be too concerned about it.

The important thing is the reviews should be done properly. One should take action on one's own belief and one shouldn't follow the herd, ie; if a user has cast his close vote, the other 4 users should form their own opinion if the question should be closed or not and only then should they cast their votes; and not blindly trust the first one and take his opinion for granted.

And, believe me, Close Review is *the* toughest review queue (at least I find it so). I don't know how so many users are able to read and vote on 20 review items in a day (mostly in one sitting within a couple of minutes). I hardly find myself to be able to review more than 4-5 items in this queue in a span of 15-20 minutes.

So, forget about numbers and make sure you review correctly. Close the ones which should be closed and leave open the ones which should be left open.

Comment: I agree with you mostly. But `N` items in queue means `N*5` number of minimum votes required of put it out(in reality, which must be much higher as votes vanish away). So I think something should be implemented to make closing faster(faster in sense of implementation, not voting. A user would still take the same time as before to review a post.) so that the number would decrease rather than increasing.

Comment: @RegisteredUser I would re-iterate.. don't care about numbers.. The current close system is quite good as it is and their isn't any need to make changes just for the sake of making changes.. I haven't touched upon any of the ideas you have recommended as it is mostly sarcasm. If you are serious about any of them, make necessary edits (or create a new feature-request/discussion question) and I would share my views on them.