# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool Ubuntu applications
- the site's Twitter account
- Ubuntu scripts or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/ads/display/12379).

Comment: If it OK to use HTTPS links to images/urls?

Comment: @Wilf according to the rules above, "Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)", so that would rule out external hosting. That being said, exceptions have been made in the past (see [this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12383/5)). If in doubt, open a question here on Meta.

Comment: @NathanOsman - just i found that for things that need  HTTPS imgur can do it happily (e.g. the inkscape one below https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DfhT.png). I mainly use this so no security errors occur when the web page is HTTPS but the contents is not - web design and development not always that fun cos of fixing stupid errors... I think it be fine unless usersuse a network that blocks HTTPS, in which case the flippin thing won't load.

Comment: @GraceNote shouldn't there be a new one?

Answer (score 31):

[image: Ubuntu Touch]

Comment: You might want to consider updating this with an image of the BQ Aquaris. (Hint: [this](http://2buntu.com/touch/device-art-generator/) might help.)

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll change the wording too since they are preferring Ubuntu phones instead of touch now.

Answer (score 23):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/askubuntu.com/bounty.png](https://askubuntu.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: How did you get this ad into the system? Normally it rejects ads without images...

Comment: It's a special one, works on all StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 23):

[image: Everything Ubuntu. Daily.]

Answer (score 22):

[image: LibreOffice: The Document Foundation!]

Comment: Hi! as the resident fella who gets frustrated by ads without borders, do you mind adding some borders to this ad so it meets our creative requirements? Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

[image: Ask Ubuntu Meta - Customize Ask Ubuntu]

Comment: Customize Ask Ubuntu? Not convinced

Comment: @don.joey Hey, I'm the one who actually designed that, what would you propose the tagline to be? [Kindly see this first](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8422/how-do-we-get-more-ask-ubuntu-users-to-use-meta)

Comment: I am thinking of - "Improve Ask Ubuntu!" What do you think?

Comment: @Parto I hope I did not discourage you stating I am not convinced. I just think that you cannot customize AU in AU meta.

Comment: @don.joey Changed.

Comment: @Parto upvoted! Just one detail: Ask **U**buntu (and not **u**buntu) would be nicer.

Comment: @don.joey Hahah. Noted. Lemme change :-)

Comment: @don.joey Done.

Answer (score 20):

[image: WebUpd8 is an Ubuntu / Linux blog which delivers daily news, tips and application reviews.]

Comment: Thanks forgot to copy it...

Answer (score 17):

[image: Inksacpe - Draw Freely]

Answer (score 17):

[image: VLC media player is a free and open source media player, encoder, and streamer made by the volunteers of the VideoLAN community. VLC uses its internal codecs to work essentially on every popular platform and read almost all files, CDs, DVDs, network streams, capture cards and other media formats!]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Review]

Comment: Hi! I'm on the team that makes sure paid advertisers adhere to creative specifications (among other things). Do you mind adding borders to this ad? Thanks!

Comment: @stevvve - paid? would love to be... done anyway.

Comment: Hahahaha I included that part so you know we have strict guidelines for them, and that those standards come from somewhere-- not just making them up to make your life extra fun! :-)

Comment: @stevvve we haven't seen this as part of the requirements for for community promotions for years - here is the community post from 2011: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1089/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011?rq=1 Is this something recent?

Comment: @Wilf can you post an updated one of this for this year's ads? The review queues are growing again.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Vi and Vim Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 12):

[image: A free, open-source game of ancient warfare]

Answer (score 12):

[image: darktable | the photo workflow software]

Comment: superb image editor for all levels of photographers but sometimes crashes and takes up a lot of resource, at least in my case.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Join your fellow community members in chat!]

Comment: The design of the image could be improved, e.g. by using less red, especially removing the reddish fog above the screenshot.

Comment: @ByteCommander: I agree!  That's an artifact of `gnome-screenshot`...  feel free to edit and replace!  (I'm not good with graphics programs)

Comment: @Fabby: I think I've improved it, but if you don't like it please revert it back or let me know what needs improving upon. :)

Comment: Ubuntu font! Ubuntu font! Can we haz Ubuntu font?

Comment: @muru: Done! :)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: I like it!

Comment: He, that's me =)

Answer (score 11):

[image: Pipelight allows you to use Windows only plugins in Linux browsers. It supports Silverlight, Unity Webplayer, Shockwave, Flash and more.]

Comment: Hallloooo! This ad requires a border because it has white space near the outside of the ad. Do you mind adding a border in to appease the ad ops gods? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

[image: We're looking for new writers too!]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Chromium is an open-source browser project that aims to build a safer, faster, and more stable way for all Internet users to experience the web]

Comment: Perhaps better link a page from which it's more obvious how to install on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 10):

[image: Software Recommendations]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Unix & Linux Stack Exchange]

Comment: I tried to make it the sharpest as I could. If you have little suggestions I can probably take care of them (simple stuff like borders / background etc). Also this is just a baseline; If someone has better skills than me at GIMP and / or a better idea, feel free to edit; here is the original sprite in SVG: http://cdn.sstatic.net/unix/img/sprites.svg

Comment: how about Unix on line, then &, then Linux?

Comment: @muru I thought about it, but I don't know if I'm allowed to modify the logo that way. Let me see if I can find the rules for reusing the logo.

Comment: their favicon is a staggered U, &, L, so I suppose some degree of accommodation to the form of presentation can be made.

Comment: @muru Ok, apparently [these rules](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) apply; the problem is they mention "Do not distort or alter our logo in any way.". I think so as well, it's not that I'm altering it *that much*. I'll make it, let's see if they have something to object.

Comment: don't worry too much. Ask on U&L Meta. I'm sure they'd agree.

Comment: @muru Done. What do you think? You were right, looks way nicer than before!

Comment: "Unix", "&" and "Linux" are all X-centered and Y-centered in their third of the height, but "Unix" and "Linux" the relatively to the height of "U" and "L". Maybe I should center those according to the height of the other letters.

Comment: looks great! +1

Answer (score 7):

[image: Blender is a free and open source 3D animation suite. Learn more]

[community-ads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/community-ads)

Comment: +1, however, for a future version of the image I would recommend to somehow make it a little more obvious that this ad is not about a computer game. For example, the image could be diagonally split into two parts: the upper half would be just like now but the lower half would show the wireframes of the 3D models.

Comment: Ooh okay, makes sense. Perhaps I can edit it?

Comment: Looking at [this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12386/137449), it indeed seems to be possible to improve an ad. Not sure about the exact “rules” for this process, though.

Comment: yes, you can edit and improve.

Comment: Well, the image is up for editing/replacing. Can't wait to see what new image comes up!

Answer (score 7):

[image: Lauchpad]

Answer (score 5):

[image: An open-source editor for experienced web designers & programmer, that supports many programming and markup languages, but focused on creating interactive websites.]

Comment: Yeahhh this needs a border to meet our specifications. Please update the ad as soon as you can. Thanks!

Comment: @stevvve - done as well, would it be easier to a 1px border to the adbox itself :)

Answer (score 4):

[image: Flightgear - Fly Free!]

Comment: Gimp XCF file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/m6euo542gwyzi7o/fgfsAD.xcf), if you want create your own (also for when I lose it later :)

Answer (score 4):

[image: GNU Parallel - for people who live life in the parallel lane]

Comment: Can you take a minute and add a border in? Borders are required for ads with white (or near-white) space along the edge of an ad. Thanks!

Comment: It is not mentioned in the image requirements. Can you take a minute and change the image requirements to include this requirement? Thanks!

Comment: Grrrumble they *were* at one point a part of the requirements. I'll speak with the powers that be to get this cleared up. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[image: Support the FIRST Robotics proposal on Area51.SE!]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Visit elementary OS Stack Exchange]

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: The official name is "elementary" without the OS last time I looked...  **;-)**

Comment: I know that, but I wonder why in the world they say "The image that you create *must* be 220 x 250 pixels" if they're going to accept also image sized 440x500px.

Comment: Ok. I'll have to redo mine for 440x500 I guess :(

Comment: @Tim: I bow to your screenshot!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Arts and Crafts Q&A]

Answer (score -2):

[image: Check out the Area 51 Remote Sensing Proposal]

Answer (score -3):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.